# I need the view document link sent to recipient (s) when digning via docusign API

Tags: docusignapi

Is there a way to obtain the view document URL sent to the recipient?
I can enumerate the envelope status pulling back a multitude of URIs.
None which seem to match the URL and parameters.

Answer (score 0):

If by *document URL* you mean the signing URL (ie. the URL token a recipient can use to sign an envelope) then no I don't believe this is possible.

URL tokens have lots of security built into them - when you generate a token it's only valid for 5 minutes and it is a one-time use, meaning if that URL is used or expired then you need to generate a new URL for that given recipient.

To help keep them even more secure if one is generated the actual link will not be saved and or returned anywhere to help prevent an attacker getting hold of it and using it before the true/intended recipient.

So as mentioned, once generated and sent there is no way to query the DocuSign system and ask for that actual URL that you've previously created.  If you want to remember each URL you generate you'll have to do that through your app logic - but take note that they will only be valid for 5 mins and a one-time usage.